# Best way to reuse data that has already been ready in a Spring Batch process

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I wrote a product processing update which adds more data to the product for printing product labels. The 2 main steps for achieving this are the productCategorizationStep step and the productDetailsConfigStep.  The product details and its categorization may or not be present. If a product's detail and categorization are not present that product is filtered from the final list products.  The problem is passing the products which could not be updated using the category information or the details information for the final productProcessingSummaryStep. The productProcessingSummaryStep creates a summary of al productIds that were processed whether the full updated occurred or not.
All the productIds will be read in the productUpdateStep i.e. the first step. How can I carry those forward without using the ItemReader again? Is it possible? Also, I need to include the productIds which could not be categorized and finally the productIds with no details update.

Here is the full configuration

```java
        import com.healthpartners.carelocation.batch.listener.JobResultListener;
        import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
        import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
        import org.springframework.batch.core.*;
        import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
        import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher;
        import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.RunIdIncrementer;
        import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
        import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
        import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
        import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
        
        import java.util.Date;
        import java.util.UUID;
        
        @Slf4j
        @Configuration
        @RequiredArgsConstructor
        public class JobConfiguration {
            @Configuration
        
                private final JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
                private final JobLauncher productAppJobLauncher;
                private final static String PRODUCT_JOB = "ProductJob";
        
                private final JobResultListener jobResultListener;
        
        
                @Qualifier("productUpdateStep")
                private final Step productUpdateStep;
        
        
                @Qualifier("productDetailsConfigStep")
                private final Step productDetailsConfigStep;
        
                @Qualifier("productCategorizationStep")
                private final Step productCategorizationStep;
        
            /**
             * This step collects all the Products for which product details were added
             * by productId. It also displays in a file the products for which details could not
             * be found like below
             *  PRODUCT_ID   DETAILS_UPDATED  CATEGORIZED
             *  12344         true            true
             *  342222        false           true
             *  32122         true            false
             */
                @Qualifier("productProcessingSummaryStep")
                private final Step productProcessingSummaryStep;
        
        
        
            @Bean("productProcessingJob")
                public Job processingJob()  {
                    return jobBuilderFactory.get(CARE_LOCATION_JOB)
                            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                            .listener(jobResultListener)
                            .start(productUpdateStep)
                            .next(productDetailsConfigStep)
                            .next(productCategorizationStep)
                            .next(productProcessingSummaryStep)
                            .build();
                }
        
        
                @Scheduled(cron = "${processing.schedule}") //3AM?
                public void runJob() throws Exception {
                    JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder()
                            .addString("jobId", UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                            .addDate("date", new Date())
                            .addLong("time", System.currentTimeMillis()).toJobParameters();
        
                    JobExecution execution = productAppJobLauncher.run(processingJob(), jobParameters);
                    log.info("STATUS :: " + execution.getStatus());
                }
        
        
        
        }
```

I know I can use a StepExecution to pass data between steps, but my implementation needs to pass the data between multiple steps, in fact to the final step that writes the final CSV File.  I'd be grateful for any help

Comment: Q: Is there a database that your application can use to track your data?

Comment: Yes, there is. It's an H2 database for the  batch JobMetadata.

Comment: Cool.  Then it sounds like one solution is to 1) create some new tables, 2) create some JPA objects to interface to the DB data in Java, 3) Add a bit of additional logic in your Java app to write and read that data you need to communicate between steps, and finally 4) Add a bit of logic to clean everything up when the job completes.  NOTE: H2 is often in-memory: you might want to persist data between restarts.

Answer (score 0):

You can access to every stepExecutionContext within one job.
`stepExecution.getJobExecution().getStepExecutions()`
More over for data which you would like to use in other steps you can use Execution context of a job. You can check here [link](https://www.linkedin.com/advice/3/how-do-you-use-spring-batch-listeners-access-modify#:%7E:text=Spring%20Batch%20is%20a%20framework,different%20components%20of%20a%20job.)

Another solution implement cache, but it will require additional reads/writes/cleanups

Comment: Does that mean the if I set the key and value in the first step productUpdateStep, it wi be available in the last step productProcessingSummaryStep? I did not see that in any of the documentation

Comment: Yes, it will be available.  Probably better to use Job Execution context level for it, but all step available within one job.